# Unobtrusive jquery with autocomplete on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Can we use unobtrusive javascript to implement features like autocomplete in jquery? or should I use the public/javscripts folder and reference each javascript that interests one of my views separately?

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup you can use autocomplete plugins from  jquery or you can build your own. More info on your problem could get a better answer, but for now, the straight answer to your question is, yes you can use autocomplete and jquery. And yes you should put all your scripts in your public/javascripts folder.

Unobtrusive JS basically means your scripts aren't found in your html. So you can just create a file like autocomplete.js in your public/javascripts folder then include it in your HTML like so:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "autocomplete" %>
```

that's as unobstrusive as you can be

Comment: can we do it with unobtrusive javascript like the method followed in this episode? http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript

Comment: which part of the episode are you referring to? i edited my answer based on what i think you mean.

Comment: The part where he creates index.js.erb jointly with index.html.erb.
It looks as though you can pair each javascript file to the particular view you will be using it in....now I think I'm not sure that's the right thing to do

Comment: ah well that depends on you actually. personally i'm not a fan of RJS but in an objective point of view, yes you can also do that. it depends on your own coding standards i guess. if you want to tie certain scripts to specific pages then go use RJS, otherwise, stick with jquery and including scripts per page. you can also go the jquery+rjs route: http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery